# Separate different zones from one attribute in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, style

I am new with QGIS and I use QGIS 2.12.3 Lyon.

I downloaded from an official web side the protected water areas. Those areas are separated in different zones (for example zone I, zone II and zone III).

On the web side I can see those different zones, unfortunately in my QGIS all those zones are in the same color, although I can see the border in between them.

Is it possible to separate the zones and put it into different colors (so that I can see on QGIS too the different zones)?

I thought I can do it with the attribute table, but I couldn’t figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

After adding the shapefile in QGIS,right click the layer and select properties, from there go to the `Style` tab and select `Categorized` This will allow you to change symbology based on a attribute, select the column you want to use (the attribute) and click `classify` this will add all the different attributes you can then style. Assign color to individual attributes as you want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To show that, it is just a rendering setting.  Try the following:

1. Right click on layer name in the Layers panel and select Properties
2. Select the Style tab, Categorized drop down, and select the field that has the zones classes defined in the Column drop down
3. Then click the Classify button and change the class symbol, size, and color as needed

[image]
*screen capture v2.6, but same idea for v2.12.*